# Laravel - How to sum child data and pass it to parent @foreach

Tags: php, laravel, sum, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

i'm new to laravel. So in this case i'm trying to sum child data and pass it to parent nominal column inside parent index @foreach,
the thing is idk how to declare the parent id inside controller

[here's my parent index which i want to show the sum child each parent id in @foreach](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5aNk.png)

[here's my child index that i've already sum it, i want to show it into parent @foreach nominal column as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z4Ykp.png)

here's my **SPJCreateController** which is parent controller

```
class SPJCreateController extends Controller
{
   public function index(Request $request, $id)
   {
      $kegiatan = DPAKegiatan::with('dpatahun')->findorfail($id);
      $data = SPJCreate::with('spjcreatedetail')
              ->where('id_dpakegiatan', $kegiatan->id)
              ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
              ->paginate(10);
      $total = SPJCreateDetail::where('id_spj', $request->id)->sum('nominal');
      return view('spj.kegiatan.create.data', compact('kegiatan','data','total'));
   }
}
```

in this controller i declare variable $total which is gonna sum column 'nominal' in SPJCreateDetail Model but idk how to declare ***where*** inside of it since $id is the id of grandparent

It returns 0 inside nominal column if i put *$request->id* inside *where*

however it shown when i call it manually like this

```
$total = SPJCreateDetail::where('id_spj', 6)->sum('nominal');
```

[my parent index after i put where id manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ft5Hl.png)

But i don't want that because i want my id to be dynamically called and sum eachrow of it

My **SPJCreate** Model which is parent model

```
class SPJCreate extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    protected $table = 'spj';
    protected $fillable = ['id_dpakegiatan','tipebelanja','tipebelanjadetail'];

    public function dpakegiatan()
    {
          return $this->belongsTo(DPAKegiatan::class, 'id_dpakegiatan');
    }

    public function spjcreatedetail()
    {
          return $this->hasMany(DPAKegiatan::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

My **SPJCreateDetail** model which is child model

```
class SPJCreateDetail extends Model
{
     protected $primaryKey = 'id';
     protected $table = 'spj_detail';
     protected $fillable = ['id_spj','id_listbelanja','ket','penerima','nominal','ppn','pph21','pph22','pph23'];

     public function spjcreate()
     {
          return $this->belongsTo(SPJCreate::class, 'id_spj');
     }
}
```

Sorry for my bad english i hope u guys can help me because im stuck for a month trying to figure it out :( , Thank you.

i dd inside my controller

```
$total = dd(SPJCreateDetail::where('id_spj', $request->id)->sum('nominal'));
```

it returns like this
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/omOrg.png)

however

```
$total = dd(SPJCreateDetail::where('id_spj', 6)->sum('nominal'));
```

it return the value correctly
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnSS3.png)

here's my web routes

```
    // --Here's my grandparent routes-- //
Route::get('/spj/kegiatan&id={spjkeg}', 'SPJKegController@index')->name('spjkeg')->middleware('auth');
    // ------------- //
        
    // --Here's my Parent Route Which is Gonna show my child sum-- //
Route::get('/spj/kegiatan/create&id={spjcreate}', 'SPJCreateController@index')->name('spj')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/spj/kegiatan/create/store&id={spjcreate}', 'SPJCreateController@store')->name('spj.store')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/spj/kegiatan/create/updt&id={spjcreate}', 'SPJCreateController@update')->name('spj.update')->middleware('auth');
Route::delete('/spj/kegiatan/create/del&id={spjcreate}', 'SPJCreateController@destroy')->name('spj.destroy')->middleware('auth');
    // ------------ //
                
    // --Here's the child route-- //
Route::get('/spj/kegiatan/create/detail&id={spjdet}', 'SPJCreateDetailController@index')->name('spj.detail')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/spj/kegiatan/create/detail/store&id={spjdet}', 'SPJCreateDetailController@store')->name('spj.detail.store')->middleware('auth');
Route::post('/spj/kegiatan/create/detail/updt&id={spjdet}', 'SPJCreateDetailController@update')->name('spj.detail.update')->middleware('auth');
Route::delete('/spj/kegiatan/create/detail/del&id={spjdet}', 'SPJCreateDetailController@destroy')->name('spj.detail.destroy')->middleware('auth');
    // ------------ //
```

Here's my View.blade.php

```
@php $no = 0; @endphp
@forelse($data as $spj => $result)
@php $no++; @endphp
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ $spj + $data->firstitem() }}.</td>
                      <td class="text-center"><b>{{ $result->tipebelanjadetail }}</b></td>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ $total }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">
                      <div class="dropdown">
                        <button data-id="{{ $result->id }}" data-idtipebelanja="{{ $result->tipebelanja }}" data-idtipebelanjadetail="{{ $result->tipebelanjadetail }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editspj" class="btn btn-success btn-s" style="background-color:#138496;border-color:#138496"><i class="fad fa-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button data-id="{{ $result->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletespj" class="btn btn-success btn-s" style="background-color:#eb1c0f;border-color:#eb1c0f"><i class="fad fa-trash"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-warning dropdown dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fad fa-info"></i></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Route('spj.detail', $result->id)}}"><i style="padding-right:5px" class="fad fa-eye"></i>Detail</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                      @empty
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">Tidak ada data <i class="far fa-frown fa-5"></i></td>
                      </tr>
@endforelse
```

Comment: @AndySong i edit the post with my dd there you can check it :) and im wrong about id 8 it's id 6 cause there's no data inside id 8

Comment: @AndySong well it returns null if i did dd($request->id) only, is the code like this?
`$total = dd(SPJCreateDetail::where('id_spj', $request->id)->sum('nominal'));
dd($request->id)`

Comment: @AndySong i updated my post with web routes in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```php
   public function index($spjcreate)
   {
      $kegiatan = DPAKegiatan::with('dpatahun')->findorfail($spjcreate);
      $data = SPJCreate::with('spjcreatedetail')
              ->where('id_dpakegiatan', $kegiatan->id)
              ->withCount(['spjcreatedetail AS total' => function ($query) {
                  $query->select(DB::raw('SUM(nominal) as total'));
              }])
              ->orderBy('created_at', 'asc')
              ->paginate(10);

      return view('spj.kegiatan.create.data', compact('kegiatan','data'));
   }
```

```html
@php $no = 0; @endphp
@forelse($data as $spj => $result)
@php $no++; @endphp
                    <tr>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ $spj + $data->firstitem() }}.</td>
                      <td class="text-center"><b>{{ $result->tipebelanjadetail }}</b></td>
                      <td class="text-center">{{ $result->total }}</td>
                      <td class="text-center">
                      <div class="dropdown">
                        <button data-id="{{ $result->id }}" data-idtipebelanja="{{ $result->tipebelanja }}" data-idtipebelanjadetail="{{ $result->tipebelanjadetail }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#editspj" class="btn btn-success btn-s" style="background-color:#138496;border-color:#138496"><i class="fad fa-pencil"></i></button>
                        <button data-id="{{ $result->id }}" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletespj" class="btn btn-success btn-s" style="background-color:#eb1c0f;border-color:#eb1c0f"><i class="fad fa-trash"></i></button>
                        <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn btn-warning dropdown dropdown-toggle" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"><i class="fad fa-info"></i></button>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu">
                                <a class="dropdown-item" href="{{ Route('spj.detail', $result->id)}}"><i style="padding-right:5px" class="fad fa-eye"></i>Detail</a>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                      @empty
                      <tr>
                        <td colspan="7" class="text-center">Tidak ada data <i class="far fa-frown fa-5"></i></td>
                      </tr>
@endforelse
```

Comment: no it won't work it will return 0 too, cause the $id is the id of grandparent which is in need because my parent data is related to that grandparent id

Comment: i try ur code but new error shown `Undefined variable: id`

Comment: sadly its still return 0 with `$spjcreate` because id `id_spj` need to be same with id `id_dpakegiatan`

Comment: or is there a way to make other findorfail method?

Comment: no im wrong about that, id from SPJCreateDetail `id_spj` need to be same as id in SPJCreate Model `id`

Comment: yes, each of them have `$total` of their own child sum. But how can i do that? it seems it cant sum each row of SPJCreateDetail inside controller? do i have to sum it inside @foreach view.blade and what is the code to achieve that result? i have the view.blade posted in it

Comment: I updated again, @kzehaya I do not have your data, do not have your code to test, but good luck.

Comment: @kzehaya my answer should work, let me know if it works, and please accept my answer if it helped you.

Comment: i try ur code it shows up, but because of this `->where('id_dpakegiatan', $kegiatan->id)` it sum based on grandparent id not parent which it cant find `id_spj`. Can i declare `where` inside this `$query->select(DB::raw('SUM(nominal) as total'));` like `where('id_spj', $data->id)` ? thx

Comment: @kzehaya I do not really understand what you mean, so the total is wrong?

Comment: it works without grandparent id in it but it doesnt work with grandparent id in it. So im currently using trigger sql to sum it, btw thx for ur code i kinda need this too so im accept your answer :)